Publish private key of testcontainer
I setup some Java integration tests with testcontainers and atomz/sftp docker container for Jsch, both running on the same machine.
I store the generated key pair in the test/resource path of my maven project.
The keypair isn't used anywhere else as on my local docker container and is only used for testing.
This is the code fragment where the private keys are used:
private static final GenericContainer<?> sftpContainer = new GenericContainer<>("atmoz/sftp:alpine")
        .withCopyFileToContainer(
                MountableFile.forClasspathResource("ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key"),
                "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key"
        )
        .withCopyFileToContainer(
                MountableFile.forClasspathResource("ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key"),
                "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key")
        .withExposedPorts(22)
        .withCommand("foo:pass:::upload");

Is it safe to add the keypair to git and push it to github?
Or are there drawbacks to this method? Are there better solutions?
Thank you in advance.

No, it is not safe to commit the private key. The user of your code is responsible for providing a key where your code can find it.

@chepner it's just for the ease of testing. In production there is a config file. I can't find a reason why it should be harmful, but I might overlook smth, that's why I'm asking. :)

If the key really doesn't matter, then it'd be a better practice to dynamically generate one as part of your test setup.

I now wrote the following code to generate keys for each test run:
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Class to generate test RSA KeyPairs
 */
public class KeyPairGenerator {
    
    private static final File privateKeyFile = new File("./src/test/resources/ssh_host_rsa_key");
    private static final File publicKeyFile = new File("./src/test/resources/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub");

    public File getPrivateKeyFile() {
        return privateKeyFile;
    }

    public File getPublicKeyFile() {
        return publicKeyFile;
    }

    /**
     * Generate RSA KeyPair
     */
    public void generate() throws IOException, JSchException {
        // Generate RSA keyPair
        JSch jSch = new JSch();
        KeyPair keyPair = KeyPair.genKeyPair(jSch, KeyPair.RSA, 4096);

        // Write Key files to file
        keyPair.writePrivateKey(privateKeyFile.getPath());
        keyPair.writePublicKey(publicKeyFile.getPath(), "sftp@docker");
        
        
    }
}

The key pair will be deleted after all tests ran.
